# how to display a wait cursor from a VB6 progran running on Windows10

Tags: vb6-migration

I have VB6 running under Windows10 operating system. It seems everything is working except the wait cursor. Screen.MousePointer = vbHourglass and Screen.MousePointer = vbDefault.

Have you ever grappled with this issue and have you ever got it to work?

A code sample would be greatly appreciated/

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. VB6 code works it was just that the wait cursor flashed so fast in windows 10 environment I did not notice it.